# Summation of rows and columns in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a table in html that should technically act as a spreadsheet. I need to sum up rows and display total on the end cell labeled total. The table should also sum the columns as well on the end column cell as well. What is the best way to attack this? I have researched jquery and tried to modify updated existing scripts  but cannot seem to get it to calculate. This is the html I set up:

```html
  <!-- Table Content Starts Here -->
    <div class="tableContent">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="ccTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="tableHdr">
                            <th scope="col" align="right">Days</th>
                            <th scope="col">S</th>
                            <th scope="col">M</th>
                            <th scope="col">T</th>
                            <th scope="col">W</th>
                            <th scope="col">T</th>
                            <th scope="col">F</th>
                            <th scope="col">S</th>
                            <th scope="col">S</th>
                            <th scope="col">M</th>
                            <th scope="col">T</th>
                            <th scope="col">W</th>
                            <th scope="col">T</th>
                            <th scope="col">F</th>
                            <th scope="col">S</th>
                            <th scope="col">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Dates</td>
                            <td>4/29</td>
                            <td>4/30</td>
                            <td>5/1</td>
                            <td>5/2</td>
                            <td>5/3</td>
                            <td>5/4</td>
                            <td>5/5</td>
                            <td>5/6</td>
                            <td>5/7</td>
                            <td>5/8</td>
                            <td>5/9</td>
                            <td>5/10</td>
                            <td>5/11</td>
                            <td>5/12</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">In</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Out</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">In</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Out</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Regular Hours</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Vacation</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Sick</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Holiday</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td align="right">Other</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size ="2"class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" align="right">Total:</td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                            <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: I think you are missing some code on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question what you want but if you want to sum up the value of column and row of a table then refer the below sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var row = 0,
    col = 0,
    ncol = 0;
  var sum;
  // sum by row
  $("tr").each(function(rowindex) {
    sum = 0;
    col = 0;
    $(this).find("td").each(function(colindex) {
      col++;
      newval = $(this).find("input").val();
      if (isNaN(newval)) {
        $(this).html(sum);
        if (col > ncol) {
          ncol = col - 1
        }
      } else {
        sum += parseInt(newval);
      }
    });
  });

  // sum by col
  for (col = 1; col < ncol + 1; col++) {
    //console.log("column: " + col);
    sum = 0;
    $("tr").each(function(rowindex) {
      $(this).find("td:nth-child(" + col + ")").each(function(rowindex) {
        newval = $(this).find("input").val();
        //console.log(newval);
        if (isNaN(newval)) {
          $(this).html(sum);
        } else {
          sum += parseInt(newval);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="3" />
    </td>
    <td class="rowsum">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="6" />
    </td>
    <td class="rowsum">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="7" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="8" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="9" />
    </td>
    <td class="rowsum">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colsum">-</td>
    <td class="colsum">-</td>
    <td class="colsum">-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `change`, `keyup` and `input` on the input inside the table and loop thru each cell to get the values.

**Note:** You need to make the total inputs not editable

```js
$(function() {

  //Add an event listener
  $('#ccTable input').bind("change keyup input", function() {

    var colValues = [];                                        //Init the col array

    $('#ccTable tbody tr:not(:last-child)').each(function() {  //Loop thru each row
      var rowValues = 0;                                       //init total of row
      $(this).find('input:not(:last)').each(function(i) {      //Loop thru each input of the row
        var val = +$(this).val() || 0;                         //Get the value of inpunt. If not a number assign 0

        rowValues += val;                                      //Add the value to rowValues 

        colValues[i] = colValues[i] || 0;                      //Init the col to 0
        colValues[i] += val;                                   //Add the value to the col
      })

      //Update row total
      $(this).find('input:last').val(rowValues.toFixed(2));
    });

    //Update col total
    $('#ccTable tbody tr:last-child').find('input:not(:last)').each(function(i) {
      $(this).val(colValues[i].toFixed(2));
    })

    //Sum all colValues and Upate the total/total cell
    var sum = colValues.reduce((c, v) => c + v);
    $('#ccTable tbody tr:last-child').find('input:last').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ccTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableHdr">
      <th scope="col" align="right">Days</th>
      <th scope="col">S</th>
      <th scope="col">M</th>
      <th scope="col">T</th>
      <th scope="col">W</th>
      <th scope="col">T</th>
      <th scope="col">F</th>
      <th scope="col">S</th>
      <th scope="col">S</th>
      <th scope="col">M</th>
      <th scope="col">T</th>
      <th scope="col">W</th>
      <th scope="col">T</th>
      <th scope="col">F</th>
      <th scope="col">S</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Dates</td>
      <td>4/29</td>
      <td>4/30</td>
      <td>5/1</td>
      <td>5/2</td>
      <td>5/3</td>
      <td>5/4</td>
      <td>5/5</td>
      <td>5/6</td>
      <td>5/7</td>
      <td>5/8</td>
      <td>5/9</td>
      <td>5/10</td>
      <td>5/11</td>
      <td>5/12</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">In</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Out</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">In</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Out</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Regular Hours</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Vacation</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Sick</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Holiday</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td align="right">Other</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td style="font-weight:bold" align="right">Total:</td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' size="2" class='editable' value='0.00' /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/59734/)

It is brief and simple.

```
calculateTable('#ccTable');

function calculate(table, e) {
  return setTimeout(()=>{
    var $rows = $(table).find('tr');

    var data = $rows
    .slice(2,-1)
    .get()
    .map(el =>
         $(el)
         .find('td:not(:first) input')
         .get()
         .map(el => parseFloat($(el).val()) || 0)
        );

    $rows.last()
      .find('td')
      .slice(1)
      .each((index, el) => {
            $(el).find('input')
                .val(data
                    .reduce((acc, val) => acc + val[index], 0)
                .toFixed(2));
        });
  });
}

function calculateTable (target) {
    handler = calculate.bind(null, target)
    $(target).find('input')
            .change(handler)
            .keypress(handler);
  handler();
}
```